# How do I handle unkown type of errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry for the title, but I don't know how to name this.

For example I have something like this:
`const randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(24).toString("base64")`
The problem I'm facing with this(or other alike) is that I don't know what kind of type of error I may receive here. It might be something that will stop the entire node.js application, async error or simply an `undefined` or `null` or empty string in case of an error.

How can I test what type of error I will get for this one above and how can I test any others alike

Comment: The code you provided is sync, I don't understand how an async error should appear here. For error handling you can use [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: I agree with JSON Derulo (wonderful username by the way), try-catching is what you might be looking for here. But f you really want to check for the type of error you could do something like `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` to get its type as a string. You could put this in your catch.

Comment: To test for the type of error that may occur in the code you provided, you can use a try-catch block. Here's an example:
`try {
  const randomBytes = crypto.randomBytes(24).toString("base64");
  // Do something with the randomBytes variable
} catch (err) {
  // Handle the error here
  console.error("An error occurred:", err);
}`

In this example, the try block contains the code that may throw an error. If an error occurs, the program will jump to the catch block, where you can handle the error. In this case, the error will be logged to the console using console.error.

Comment: The general rule is that things throw exceptions, and you shouldn't catch _anything_ unless you have a specific idea how it might fail and what you want to do about it. Most functions tend (like your example) tend to never really fail, and in the really rare case that they do it's probably better to let the entire application crash, because it's better to crash than to try to keep an unstable/unpredictable system running

Answer (score 0):

One good way to test this is to write unit tests for it. This will allow you to test various scenarios and isolate the code to ensure that it behaves as expected in each case. You can also use a tool like Jest, which allows you to set up test suites with assertion functions to ensure that the code behaves as expected. You can also use a tool like Sinon, which allows you to stub out functions and test the results. Finally, you can use a tool like Node Inspector to debug the code and see what errors are thrown when certain conditions are met.

1. Unit Testing

Using a unit testing framework, such as Jest, you can write tests to simulate different scenarios and check if the code is working as expected. This can include checking for errors, validating the output, and ensuring that all the intended functionality is working properly.

2. Stubbing

Using a tool like Sinon, you can stub out functions in order to test different scenarios. This involves replacing a function with a dummy version of itself so the test can be run without changing the original code. This is useful for testing error cases without having to actually throw an error.

3. Debugging

Using a tool like Node Inspector, you can set breakpoints in the code and debug it step-by-step. This allows you to see what errors are being thrown and where they are coming from. This is useful for pinpointing the exact issue and making sure it is being properly handled.